# Installing Qt tools for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I've tried installing the Qt tools for Visual Studio 3 times now.  Each time, the results are not usable.  All the instructions I'm seeing on the web are from clearly much earlier versions.  The main problem I'm having now is that the Qt UI application template isn't showing up in the list of project types.  I've seen instructions that say I should see a Qt menu item in VS and that isn't happening, but maybe that's from a past version.  Does anyone have any experience with how to correctly install the Qt Tools in the current Visual Studio version?

A secondary question is, assuming one gets the tools installed, can you use the VS designer view, when using Qt form elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although I don't use the addon at all, I use CMake instead of QMake to generate my Visual Studio projects I just use `designer.exe` to edit my .ui files. You can even launch it directly from Visual Studio if you want by adding designer.exe as a .ui file handler. Right click on a .ui file in Solution Explorer and click Open With and add designer to the list.

Comment: That's sounds like it might be exactly the right solution, thanks!